# Two sided PDFs, what's the difference?

Tags: pdf, printing

So I wanted to download the Beej's Network Programming guide, available [here](http://www.beej.us/guide/bgnet/).
There are two links for A4 sized PDFs, one for 'one sided' and the other for 'two sided'. What is the difference supposed to be when printing them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On the two-sided variant, the page numbers alternate left and right so they always appear at the outer corner.  That's the major difference.

Comment: Not to mention when you bind them, you need different margins for either left/right depending on whether the page is on the "inside" part and the "outside" part.

Answer (score 3):

The layout of the pages (check out page numbers for example).

But for all practical purposes they are the same - these are purely decorative issues.

Comment: So for printing any one of the two will be just fine?

Comment: @David McDavidson - Yes.